# How to upload files to Google Drive with Python script through Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, windows-task-scheduler

I am looking to automatically upload files (specifically photos) to my google drive account through Windows Task Scheduler. This script below will successfully upload the desired photos when running the script manually; however, when attempting to automate through Task Scheduler, it doesn't work, and I am unable to hone in on the issue. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive


gauth = GoogleAuth()           
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)  



upload_file_list = ['ex_photo_name1.jpg', 'ex_photo_name2.jpg']
for upload_file in upload_file_list:

    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    # Try to load saved client credentials
    gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
    if gauth.credentials is None:
        # Authenticate if they're not there
        gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
    elif gauth.access_token_expired:
        # Refresh them if expired
        gauth.Refresh()
    else:
        # Initialize the saved creds
        gauth.Authorize()
    # Save the current credentials to a file
    gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
    
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
    
    textfile = drive.CreateFile()
    textfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
    textfile.Upload()

    
    drive.CreateFile({'id':textfile['id']}).GetContentFile(upload_file)
```

As mentioned above, I've had success uploading with this script when running manually, but when adding the .py to a .bat file (see below for reference - Setup: informs which packages to install  |  Script: python script listed above) to set up the Task Scheduler job, it does not upload anything to the Google Drive account.

```
@echo off
python "path\to\python\Setup.py" %*
python "path\to\python\script.py" %*
pause
```

Comment: Windows doesn't know what to do with Python code inside of a bat file. For Task scheduler you need to tell it the exact path to your python.exe and supply it with the argument of your script, e.g. `<path>\<to>\<python>\python.exe myscript.py`. To help debug, you can temporarily redirect any outputs or error messages to a file:  `<path>\<to>\<python>\python.exe myscript.py > c:\temp\debug.txt`

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. I've edited my post to include how my .bat file is set-up. Does that make sense, or should I add additional lines to make sure Task Scheduler knows where python is saved, etc.?

Comment: @mitchell_nelson, if python.exe is in the path of the user that runs the task, then the bat might work. Not sure why you'd need Setup.py. I must confess that I don't know what the `%*` does. I also don't know what pause will do in a scheduled task. Pause might be good for debugging but you'll probably want to REM it out for a scheduled task. If python.exe is not in the path of the user (test by typing "python" in command prompt), then you'll probably need to add full path in your path file. Also try debugging suggestions in first comment with a Run Now.